# What's the combination of an IP address and port number called?

Tags: networking, ip, port, naming

I have a structure which unites IP address and port number. What's a proper name for such a thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), it's called a *socket address*.

Answer (score 4):

The .NET framework calls it an `IPEndPoint`.

Comment: @JohnLock If you think an answer is useful, you can click on the 'up' arrow at the left to give it a vote.

Comment: It seems that I don't have enough reputation, "15" needed